# Нужно написать условие для вывода на экран имен начинающихся на маленькую букву

Tags: java, unicode

Нужно написать условие для вывода на экран имен начинающихся на маленькую букв используя класс String. Примере с окончанием фамилий на "ко".

```
public static void KO(ArrayList<Person> pp )
{
    for (Person p : pp)
    {
        if(p.lName.endsWith("ko"))
        {
            System.out.println( p );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так toLowerCase() преобразует в нижний регистр, а мне нужно что-бы вывелись имена, которые только с маленькой буквы. Не затрагивая сами имена.

Comment: Да, ты был прав. Так тоже работает. Снимаю шляпу :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(p.fName.startsWith(p.fName.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Character.isLowerCase( "somestring".codePointAt( 0 ) )
```